# Изменение вида DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Выполняю загрузку из SQL запроса в DataFrame Pandas.
Получаю вид:

```
 Index   Name    Date
  0      name_1  строка (date1_1, date1_2...date1_n)
  1      name_2  строка (date2_1, date2_2...date2_n)
  2      name_3  строка (date3_1, date3_2...date3_n)
 ...     ...     ...
  n      name_n  строка (daten_1, daten_2...daten_n)
```

Пытаюсь привести в вид:

```
   name_1   name_2   name_3 ... name_n
   date1_1  date2_1  date3_1 ... daten_1
   date1_2
   date1_3
   ....
   date1_n
```

Comment: вы можете привести небольшой (5-7 строк) воспроизводимый пример с датами в виде дат и то что должно из этого получиться?

Comment: @MaxU Добавил картинку того, что получаю я. 
Пытаюсь добиться
вместо названия столбцов имена из name_test, в строках - данные из meas

Comment: Вы можете добавить дата сет в виде текста - так чтобы мы могли его скопировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос...

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [385]: df
Out[385]:
    name              meas
0  name1     0.1, 0.2, 0.3
1  name2  0.11, 0.22, 0.33
```

сначала разобъем значения из столбца `meas` в отдельные столбцы:

```
In [386]: df = df.join(df.pop('meas').str.split(',\s*', expand=True).add_prefix('meas_'))

In [387]: df
Out[387]:
    name meas_0 meas_1 meas_2
0  name1    0.1    0.2    0.3
1  name2   0.11   0.22   0.33
```

теперь можно транспонировать получившуюся матрицу:

```
In [389]: res = df.set_index('name').T

In [390]: res
Out[390]:
name   name1 name2
meas_0   0.1  0.11
meas_1   0.2  0.22
meas_2   0.3  0.33
```

чтобы преобразовать строки в числовые значения:

```
In [407]: res = res.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

In [408]: res.dtypes
Out[408]:
name
name1    float64
name2    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Спасибо! Добавил свой вариант, слегка в лоб

Answer (score 1):

Cделал слегка в лоб:

```
meas = date.meas.str.split(',',expand=True).T
name = list((date.name_test).values)
meas.columns = name
meas = meas.astype('float64')
```